# add js function as parameter in url.action

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, url, webgrid

I want to change the value of a textbox at runtime.

I have this JavaScript function, which returns a textbox value:

```
function getValue(str) {
   var textboxValue = document.getElementById(str).value;
   return textboxValue;
}
```

This is my link:

```
wg.Column(
        header: " add ", format: @<text>
        <a href="@Url.Action("updateOrder", "MyController", new { VaraId = item.id,  pris = // Here I want to call function getValue("pris") }) ">
      ADD NEW
        </a>
        </text>)
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your anchor tag as clean and set HTML 5 data attributes for your parameter values.

```
<a class="myLink" href="@Url.Action("updateOrder", "MyController")"
        data-itemid = @item.id data-pris="pris">ADD NEW </a>
```

Now listen to the click event on this anchor tag and build the target url and naviage to taht.

```
$(function(){

  $("a.myLink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var _this=$(this);
     var calculatedVal=getValue(_this.data("pris"));
     var target=_this.attr("href")+"?VaraId="+_this.data("itemid")+
                                                      "&pris="+calculatedVal ;
     window.location.href=target;
  });

});
```

Assuming you have jQuery loaded to your page.

If your `getValue` function is simply returning the value of the element, you may use jQuery selector to get the value.

```
$(function(){

  $("a.myLink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var _this=$(this);
     var calculatedVal=$("#"+_this.data("pris")).val();
     var target=_this.attr("href")+"?VaraId="+_this.data("itemid")+
                                                       "&pris="+calculatedVal ;
     window.location.href=target;
  });

});
```

Comment: i think it should be another simple solution, this one seems so complicated